# How to extract bitmap out of Direct3D 11 Texture2D object?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, screenshot, direct3d11

I am using the Desktop Duplication API (C++) and have created an output duplication object and further queried the interface for a ID3D11Texture2D object.

I have tried using "D3DX11SaveTextureToFile" and "DirectX::SaveWICTextureToFile" but it gives an error. I need to extract the bitmap or pixel buffer out of this texture so that I can save it as an image. I have tried using a subresource and ID3D11DeviceContext::Map function to extract the pixel buffer but it seems to be empty. But context->Draw() seems to work.

Is there anyway I can extract the pixel buffer/bitmap/image out of the texture2D object?

Thanks!

UPDATE : I solved this using the `CaptureTexture` function in DirectXTex. You can create a `HBITMAP` from the resultant `ScratchImage`

Comment: What's the HRESULT error you are getting?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn : D3DX11SaveTextureToFile gives "Attempted to create a device with the debug layer enabled and the layer is not installed" Directx::SaveWICTextureToFile gives "No such interface supported"

Comment: D3DX11 is deprecated and hasn't been updated in many years, so the error output is probably trying to turn ``E_NOINTERFACE`` into something meaningful which it isn't anymore. Can you tell me exactly which line of code in ``ScreenGrab.cpp`` or ``DirectXTexWIC.cpp`` where you are seeing this error generated?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn : `IWICImagingFactory* pWIC = _GetWIC();` is failing and the return is `E_NOINTERFACE`

Comment: What OS are you using? Which vcxproj/sln file or NuGet version of DirectXTex are you using? Depending on how you build the code, ``_GetWIC`` will either try to use WIC2 and then WIC1, or just WIC1. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/19/windows-imaging-component-and-windows-8.aspx)

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn : Using Windows 8.1; I'm using the one bundled with DirectX SDK (June 2010), but I'm not using `D3DX**Tex` headers. I'm using `ScreenGrab.cpp` from `DirectXTK`. There are two externed definitions - `_GetWIC()` and `_IsWic2()` which are undefined when I'm using the debugger.
Instead of using WIC to save image, is there anyway I can get the pixel buffer? I tried using `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map` but the `pData` array is empty.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For those who are getting `E_NOINTERFACE` as their return code from `DirectX::SaveWICTextureToFile`, you need to initialize COM using one of the following:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(nullptr); // Single threaded

HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED);  // For multithreaded programs
```

Don't forget to call `CoUninialize()` after you are done.  This is because WIC uses COM and must be initialized before using it.